# C# WebRequest download as Gzip, but don't decompress

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, gzipstream

How can I tell WebRequest to **not** decompress the gzipped response ?

The response does not need to be decompressed because it will be passed along to another function that expects a Gzipped stream.

As far as I can tell, setting the AutomaticDecompression to None will tell WebRequest to download the uncompressed response ?

```
webRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
```

This relates to [C# Stream Response from 3rd party, minimal buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37536784/c-sharp-stream-response-from-3rd-party-minimal-buffering/37538628#37538628)