# How to return big file in ASP.NET MVC as a FileStreamResult straight away without waiting for it to be fully downloaded on server side?

Tags: asp.net, file, model-view-controller, stream

I'm trying to get a file which size is 100MB and return a stream result. I have to wait for "Save as..." window for about 1 minute until it is fully downloaded on server side and then after choosing file name and accepting - it saves very quickly without showing progress. But when I return a file from file system as FilePathResult, it works good.

Example:

```cs
public async Task<FileResult> GetFile()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var response = await client.GetAsync("https://speed.hetzner.de/1GB.bin");
    var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

    return File(stream, "application/zip");
}
```

What should I do to display "Save as..." window straight away and then see how much bytes were actually downloaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this question for a solution: [C# Stream Response from 3rd party, minimal buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37536784/c-sharp-stream-response-from-3rd-party-minimal-buffering/37538628)

Comment: It works! Thank you :)